# how to use != in terraform data block

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to get a list of ec2 instance ids, but the following is wrong, how can I get all the ec2 except Role = ngx?

```
data "aws_instances" "ec2" {
  filter {
    name   = "Role"
    values != ["ngx"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. First `Role` is the **wrong filter**. Maybe you wanted `iam-instance-profile.arn`? Second, you **can't do inverse searches**.

You have to get all the instances, and the filter it yourself in `locals`.

Comment: role is a tag that I defined on every server, if I want to get all ec2 ids except role=ngx, what should I do?

Comment: @jiafengzhu Same: " get all the instances, and the filter it yourself in locals".

Comment: This answer would be improved by showing how to filter it in locals.